# inheritAttrs false not working with class attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have this parent component:

```html
<StyleOutsideParenthesis :value="item.title" class="text-uppercase" />
```

And the `StyleOutsideParenthesis`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-bind="$attrs">{{this.main}}</span>
    <span v-if="this.extra">({{this.extra}})</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    computed: {
      parts() {
        return this.value.replace(/\)$/, '').split('(');
      },
      main() {
        return this.parts[0];
      },
      extra() {
        return this.parts[1];
      }
    },
    props: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

But in the end, the `<div>` still gets the `text-uppercase` class, instead of the first `<span>`.

I don't understand why as this is explicitly the example of the doc: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Notice at the bottom of the [docs for `inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs):

> Note: this option does **not** affect `class` and `style` bindings.

One way to solve this is to declare a prop that could be bound to the `span`'s `class`:

```html
<!-- StyleOutsideParenthesis.vue -->
<template>
  <div>             
    <span :class="_class" v-bind="$attrs">{{ this.main }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
       
    _class: String,
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<!-- App.vue -->                               
<StyleOutsideParenthesis :value="item.title" _class="text-uppercase" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-forward-class-to-inner-el?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FStyleOutsideParenthesis.vue)